# How to dynamically update cell reference in double quotes?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, custom-functions-excel

I'm using a custom function that I found [here](https://superuser.com/questions/602216/how-do-you-write-an-excel-formula-that-will-paste-a-specific-value-in-a-differen) to retroactively set values in other cells based on new information in later cells. The issue is, however, that the input of SetCellValue is a cell reference in quotes, like this:

```
SetCellValue("G3",16)
```

I need a way that I can change the reference in quotes (G3 in this example) to whichever cell I need to work with. I've tried using different logical tests and concatenation to no avail. I'm also going to be working with a very large set of data, so manually changing the references is pretty unfeasible. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Say you want it to refer to cell H1.
Try replacing "G3" (from your example in question) and put =H1  (try with and without quotes)

Comment: Doing that does write the value to H1, but it still doesn't allow me to dynamically change it when I autofill across several columns/rows. It also still has to be in quotes.